# D3.js - JSON data array is binding the same array element to everything

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am loading a GeoJSON data file that contains an array of objects, each object containing the vector information for a different country's outline. The same array element is being bound to every DOM element. I have come across this scope issue before in JavaScript but every change I made caused nothing to load.

I attached a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gjn5u3ur/1/). I use an example data file which seems to take a couple seconds to load.

My code from the jsfiddle looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  d3.json(
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datasets/geo-boundaries-world-110m/master/countries.geojson",
    function(error, data) {
      var myGeoJSON = data.features;

      for (i = 0; i < myGeoJSON.length; i++) {
        var path = d3.geo.path();
        var width = 960;
        var height = 600;
        var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
          .attr("width", width)
          .attr("height", height);

        svg.selectAll("path")
          .data(data.features)
          .enter().append("path")
          .attr("d",path)
          .attr("fill","#3e429a");
      }
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: You're incrementing i, but you're not using i inside your loop, or myGeoJSON for that matter.

Comment: Sorry I will edit that it breaks if I increment i, brb with the error

Comment: d3 comes back w/ cannot read length of undefined

Comment: So, I assume you checked that the data is OK?

Comment: Data seems fine, you can use something like `.data([data.features[i]])` to load the polygons individually. Then you'd need also to center on the countries (scroll down a bit to see some countries in focus)

Comment: The geodata file you gave us only contains the data for the United States... Remove the for loop and it renders the one country as it should.

Comment: @honerlawd if you follow the link directly you will see that there is data for around 150 countries

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't need to loop through the array of features. Your data file is a FeatureCollection, which [D3 can draw](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Paths#_path), either as a single path element:

```
svg.append("path").datum(data).attr("d", d3.geo.path());
```

or as separate path elements, one for each feature (country):

```
svg.selectAll("path").data(data.features)
  .enter().append("path").attr("d", d3.geo.path())
```

By default D3 uses the projection [`d3.geo.albersUsa()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Projections#albersUsa) which brings Hawaii to Mexico and Alaska to just outside the tropics. You can switch to the [equirectangular projection](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Projections#equirectangular) to see the whole world:

```js
d3.json(
  "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datasets/geo-boundaries-world-110m/6cf0946a0f4d027d21686e8402f19b524c4f6385/countries.geojson",
  function(error, data) {
    var projection = d3.geo.equirectangular();
    var path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);
    var width = 960;
    var height = 600;
    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height);

    svg.selectAll("path")
      .data(data.features)
      .enter().append("path")
      .attr("d", path)
      .attr("fill", "#3e429a");
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

---

Epilogue: I initially tried to use the more common [Mercator projection](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Projections#mercator), only to find that [it cannot handle Antarctica](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/d3-js/cw2cyzdc3Jw). D3 draws the shape for the continent, then fills the rest of the oceans instead.

In the same D3 forum thread, the author of D3 [mentioned a bug in the TopoJSON tool](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/d3-js/cw2cyzdc3Jw/g5U1yO-5JXkJ) used to generate maps, so it might be an issue with the data file you use. If you prefer Mercator, you might need to work with the maintainer of [geo-boundaries-world-110m](https://github.com/datasets/geo-boundaries-world-110m/) to fix the data file, or just exclude Antarctica from your maps.

Demo of Antarctica in Mercator:

```js
d3.json(
  "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datasets/geo-boundaries-world-110m/6cf0946a0f4d027d21686e8402f19b524c4f6385/countries.geojson",
  function(error, data) {
    var projection = d3.geo.mercator();
    var path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);
    var width = 960;
    var height = 600;
    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height);

    var antarctica = data.features.splice(6, 1);
    // now "data" has the rest of the world
    svg.selectAll("path")
      .data(antarctica)
      .enter().append("path")
      .attr("d", path)
      .attr("stroke", "red").attr("stroke-width", 10)
      // thick borders so we can see the odd paths
      .attr("fill", "#3e429a");
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: TIL `d3.geo.equirectangular` exists. Thank you.

Comment: @approxiblue. Thank You. I would have been clawing at that for weeks. Off the top of your head can you recommend any tools for debugging D3 particularly to monitor what is going on between the controller and the view? I am new to d3 and the process involved with binding d3 data to the view

Comment: @Four_lo You can put [`console.log` calls in a position function](http://www.recursion.org/d3-for-mere-mortals/). That and the browser's JS debugger (break your code into multiple lines so you can set breakpoints in more places). I haven't done D3 often enough to require more specialized tools.

Comment: @approxiblue Great! Thank You, I appreciate your help.