# D3.js Tooltip Only Appears with Inspect/Console Open

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I am creating a linechart in D3.js (v6), with 6 data points. When the user mouses over each datapoint, a tooltip should appear like in the image below.

[linechart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6InI.png)

However, the tooltip only appears when I inspect the page. Otherwise it does not appear. I think my svg may be blocking the tooltip div?

Code is below:

```
d3.json("d3_test_data.json"
).then(function(data) {


var margin = {top: 50, right:100, bottom: 50, left: 100}
, width = window.innerWidth - margin.left - margin.right  
, height = window.innerHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom; 

var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d")

data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = parseTime(d.date)})


var xScale = d3.scaleTime()
    .domain(d3.extent(data.map(function(d) {return d.date})))
    .range([ 0, width ]);

var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0,100])
    .range([height, 0]);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")


// ADD TITLE
svg.append("text")
    .attr("x", (width / 2))             
    .attr("y", 0 - (margin.top / 2))
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")  
    .style("font-size", "16px") 
    .style("text-decoration", "underline")  
    .text("TEFScore");

// ADD X AXIS
svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "x axis")
.attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
.call(d3.axisBottom(xScale)
.tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%b %d"))
.tickValues(data.map(function(d) {return d.date})));

svg.append("text")             
.attr("transform",
        "translate(" + (width/2) + " ," + 
                        (height + 40) + ")")
.style("text-anchor", "middle")
.text("Date");

//  Create Line
var score_line = d3.line()
    .x(d => xScale(d.date))
    .y(d => yScale(d.total_score))

svg.append("path")
.datum(data)
.attr("class", "line")
.style("stroke", "green")
.style("fill", "none")
.attr("d", score_line)
.attr("class", "score_line")

var tip = d3
.tip()
.attr('class', 'd3-tip')
.offset([100, -50])
.html(
    (EVENT, d) => 
    `<table><tbody>
    <tr><td class='wide'><strong><span id='purple'>Total Score: ` + d.total_score + `</span></strong></td></tr>
    <tr><td class='wide'>Lesson Score: ` + d.lesson_score + `</td></tr>
    <tr><td class='wide'>Gap Score: ` + d.gap_score + `</td></tr>
    <tr><td class='wide'>Homework Score: ` + d.hw_score + `</td></tr>
    <tr><td class='wide'>No Show Score: ` + d.no_show_score + `</td></tr>
    <tr><td class='wide'>Effort Score: ` + d.effort_score + `</td></tr>
    <tr><td class='wide'>Prep Score: ` + d.prep_score + `</td></tr>
    <tr><td class='wide'>Lateness Score: ` + d.lateness_score + `</td></tr>
    <tr><td class='wide'>Late Cancellation Score: ` + d.late_cancellations_score + `</td></tr>
    </tbody></table>`
)

var circles = svg.selectAll(".circle")
.data(data)
.enter()


circles.append("circle")
.attr("cx", d => xScale(d.date))
.attr("cy", d => yScale(d.total_score))
.attr("r", 12)
.style("fill", "white")


// Adds text to circles
circles.append("text")
.data(data)
.attr("x", d => xScale(d.date))
.attr("y", d => yScale(d.total_score) + 3)
.text(d => d.total_score)
.style("fill", "orange")
.style("font-size", "11px")
.style("font-weight", "bold")
.style("text-anchor", "middle")
.on("mouseover", tip.show)
.on("mouseout", tip.hide)

svg.call(tip)
})
```

CSS here:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .d3-tip {
        /* display: inline-block; */
        position: absolute;
        opacity: 0;
        line-height: 1;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: small;
        padding: 12px;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
        color: #fff;
        border-radius: 2px;
        z-index: 99999;
    } 
</style>
```

And here is some test json data I'm using to build the viz.

```
[
    {
    "date": "2020-04-08",
    "lesson_score": 24.06,
    "gap_score": 20,
    "hw_score" : 0,
    "no_show_score": 15,
    "effort_score": 5,
    "prep_score": 5,
    "lateness_score": 5,
    "late_cancellations_score": 5,
    "total_score": 68.06
    },
    {
    "date": "2020-04-15",
    "lesson_score": 24.06,
    "gap_score": 20,
    "hw_score" : 0,
    "no_show_score": 15,
    "effort_score": 5,
    "prep_score": 5,
    "lateness_score": 5,
    "late_cancellations_score": 5,
    "total_score": 77.06
    },
    {
    "date": "2020-04-22",
    "lesson_score": 27.16,
    "gap_score": 20,
    "hw_score": 0,
    "no_show_score": 15,
    "effort_score": 5,
    "prep_score": 5,
    "lateness_score": 9,
    "late_cancellations_score": 5,
    "total_score": 77.06
    },
    {
    "date": "2020-04-28",
    "lesson_score": 21.06,
    "gap_score": 20,
    "hw_score": 0,
    "no_show_score": 15,
    "effort_score": 4.9,
    "prep_score": 2,
    "lateness_score": 5,
    "late_cancellations_score": 5,
    "total_score": 71.06
    },
    {
    "date": "2020-05-05",
    "lesson_score": 24.06,
    "gap_score": 20,
    "hw_score": 0,
    "no_show_score": 15,
    "effort_score": 4.6,
    "prep_score": 5,
    "lateness_score": 5,
    "late_cancellations_score": 5,
    "total_score": 75.06
    },
    {
    "date": "2020-05-12",
    "lesson_score": 21.06,
    "gap_score": 20,
    "hw_score": 0,
    "no_show_score": 15,
    "effort_score": 4,
    "prep_score": 5,
    "lateness_score": 5,
    "late_cancellations_score": 5,
    "total_score": 79.06
    }
]
```

I'm not really a web developer so I may be misunderstanding how the DOM is organized here, leading to my tooltip being hidden. I've tried setting the z-index as 9999 but that hasn't worked.

Could anyone help me understand what's going on here?

Thanks!

Comment: Make it a runnable stack snippet and/or a jsfiddle like this poster did. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32903210/d3-js-json-data-array-is-binding-the-same-array-element-to-everything/33073349 and this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33384960/how-to-display-the-size-as-tooltip-in-a-d3-graph Here's a question with almost the same title as your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46552862/d3-tooltips-not-showing-up

Comment: It looks like the issue is your placement of the tooltip `div`.  It appears on top of the SVG element you are moused over on so when it appears the cursor is now on the tooltip and causes `mouseout` event to fire.  If you change the `.offset` so they don't overlap it is fine.  This is curious, though, as the `div` has `pointer-events:none` set...

Comment: Wow yep, removing the offset fixed it. Thanks a ton @Mark